# How to append the output from ProcessBuilder to file,without overwriting the exisiting data in file

Tags: java, file, process, processbuilder

While trying to append the Output from `ProcessBuilder` to file using 
`redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(outFile).file())`, it always overwrites the existing data in the file , instead of appending the data to the existing file.

How to append data to an existing file from processbuilder

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A quick look in the public and free API of `ProcessBuilder.Redirect` reveals that there is a method `appendTo()`. You may have stumbled over this method too by using your IDEs *intellisense* feature...

Answer (score 5):

```
redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(outFile).file())
```

You're losing the append information. This should be:

```
redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(outFile))
```

Comment: But when using `redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(outFile))` throws illegalArugumentException

Comment: So post the code and the stack trace and let's look at that new question. According to the Javadoc this works.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Redirect invalid for reading: redirect to append to file "./logs/AdminClient.log"
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.java:703)` this is execption

Comment: This is the exception on `redirectInput()`. You're supposed to be calling `redirectOutput()`. You said so yourself.